# How can I hidden data in JSON if variable is empty

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest

I got a some trouble in my Laravel application, in Search function, when I do search the result is

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 8,
            "identity_number": "213918273",
            "name": "Pekerja_2",
            "gender_id": 1,
            "date_of_birth": "1999-05-25",
            "address": "Jalan Bandung Raya no 50",
            "province_id": 32,
            "city_id": 3273,
            "district_id": 3273160,
            "phone": "4232343432",
            "image": null,
            "created_at": "2018-01-11 10:59:54",
            "updated_at": "2018-01-11 10:59:54",
            "partner_id": null,
            "skill": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "worker_id": 2,
                    "skill_id": 6,
                    "sub_skill_id": 18,
                    "created_at": "2018-01-15 13:06:48",
                    "updated_at": "2018-01-15 13:06:48",
                    "price": null,
                    "unit": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 16,
            "identity_number": "213918273",
            "name": "Pekerja_3",
            "gender_id": 1,
            "date_of_birth": "1999-05-25",
            "address": "Jalan Bandung Raya no 50",
            "province_id": 32,
            "city_id": 3273,
            "district_id": 3273160,
            "phone": "2345234234",
            "image": null,
            "created_at": "2018-01-15 13:06:48",
            "updated_at": "2018-01-15 13:06:48",
            "partner_id": null,
            "skill": []
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see that "Skill" with id number 3 is empty, I want all in id number 3 is empty also.
My controller is :

```
  $worker = Worker::with(['skill' => function($q) use ($request) {
        $q->where('worker_skills.sub_skill_id', $request['sub_skill_id']);
    }])->whereHas('skill');
```

And I want something like this :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 8,
            "identity_number": "213918273",
            "name": "Pekerja_2",
            "gender_id": 1,
            "date_of_birth": "1999-05-25",
            "address": "Jalan Bandung Raya no 50",
            "province_id": 32,
            "city_id": 3273,
            "district_id": 3273160,
            "phone": "2534234234",
            "image": null,
            "created_at": "2018-01-11 10:59:54",
            "updated_at": "2018-01-11 10:59:54",
            "partner_id": null,
            "skill": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "worker_id": 2,
                    "skill_id": 6,
                    "sub_skill_id": 18,
                    "created_at": "2018-01-15 13:06:48",
                    "updated_at": "2018-01-15 13:06:48",
                    "price": null,
                    "unit": null
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

The point is, if "skill" variable is empty then data not show and vice versa.
Thankyou any help will appreciate, sorry for bad english

Comment: sounds like a job for [After Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) By just deleting all null value elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a callback to your `whereHas` function with the same filter as the `with` function

```
$worker = Worker::with(['skill' => function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->where('worker_skills.sub_skill_id', $request['sub_skill_id']);
}])
->whereHas('skill', function($q) use ($request) {
    $q->where('worker_skills.sub_skill_id', $request['sub_skill_id']);
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this  `$worker = Worker:has('skill')->get();` 
Only worker that have at least one skill are contained in the collection